# Is it possible to get information about a busy Alsa device?

Tags: alsa, libalsa

Currently I am attempting to get information about an Alsa device by calling the `snd_pcm_open` function then passing that to `snd_pcm_info` to get information about the device. I plan specifically to get the channel information from `snd_pcm_query_chmaps`. The error code I am getting is: `Device or resource busy`. I was curious if there was another way to get this information or somehow open the pcm in a way that it won't ever be "busy" from other applications. How would I get this information, if at all possible, in a way that will work even if the device is busy?

The relevant snippet of my code is

```
snd_pcm_t* pcm;
int err;
if ((err = snd_pcm_open(&pcm, name, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0)) == 0 || (err = snd_pcm_open(&pcm, name, SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0)) == 0) {
    snd_pcm_info_t* pcm_info;
    if (snd_pcm_info_malloc(&pcm_info) == 0) {
        if (snd_pcm_info(pcm, pcm_info) == 0) {
            printf("Card number: %d\n", snd_pcm_info_get_card(pcm_info));
            printf("Device number: %d\n", snd_pcm_info_get_device(pcm_info));
            printf("Subdevice number: %d\n", snd_pcm_info_get_subdevice(pcm_info));
        }
        snd_pcm_info_free(pcm_info);
    }
    snd_pcm_close(pcm);
} else {
    printf("Erroring opening PCM device with error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get information about a PCM device without opening it, open the control device of its card and call [snd_ctl_pcm_info()](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/control_8c.html#ac5a9750f9ba7749efddb0d92747255c8). (See the [aplay source code](http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-utils.git;a=blob;f=aplay/aplay.c;hb=HEAD) for how to use it.)

The channel map information is provided in the TLV information of some mixer controls; use the [snd_pcm_query_chmaps_from_hw()](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#gae766a086ec64ec1189a87da3e54b8441) helper function to read it.

Comment: I have later realized that there is a way to get the channel map information from the function `snd_pcm_query_chmaps_from_hw` as the documentation said it doesn't require opening the PCM. Your pointer to `snd_ctl_pcm_info` was more than helpful though :)